# FK dubble knee joint controller circular dependency

Tags: rigging

I want to add a controller bone that is positioned by its parent bone witch is also constrained to it.

I know that this create a circular dependency but is there a way to get the controller to follow the lower bone without creating this circular dependency?

Since the controllers position is locked and not effected by input it should be possible for the position to be controlled by a constraint without creating a circular dependency.

[image]

[EDIT]
By disabling Inherit Rotation on the controlling bone I get a more stable result, and that makes sense. If I use Clear User Transform, it still doesn't reset as it should.

[image]